# Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, numpy, tcp, ros

I am getting data using a TCP and trying it to publish it in std_msgs/Float64MultiArray format, however when I am trying to convert the json data to numpy array I am getting the following error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Int32MultiArray is not JSON serializable
```

Code for receiving data from tcp and sending it to rosbridge (topic chatter)

```
import roslibpy
import socket
import time
import struct
import numpy as np
import json
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
from rospy_tutorials.msg import Floats
from std_msgs.msg import String,Int32,Int32MultiArray,MultiArrayLayout,MultiArrayDimension,Float64MultiArray

# ROS Python Bridge 
client = roslibpy.Ros(host='localhost', port=9090)  #same as rosbridge port
client.run()
print("Is ROS connected? ",client.is_connected)


talker = roslibpy.Topic(client, '/chatter', 'std_msgs/Float64MultiArray')
data_to_send = Float64MultiArray()  # the data to be sent, initialise the array


HOST = "0.0.0.0"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 8081  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print(f"Connected by {addr}")
            while client.is_connected:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                conn.sendall(data)

                data = json.loads(data)
                data_list = data[0]
               
                x_val = data_list['x']
                y_val = data_list['y']
                z_val = data_list['z']

                pos_arry = np.unique([x_val,y_val,z_val])
                pos_arry = pos_arry.tolist()
                my_array_for_publishing = Int32MultiArray(data=pos_arry)
                    
                print(type(pos_arry))

                talker.publish(roslibpy.Message({'data': my_array_for_publishing}))
                print('Sending message...')
                  
talker.unadvertise()
client.terminate()
```

Comment: Full error message please, so we don't have to guess or deduce what line might be producing this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be resolve by sending the data in list format.

```
pos_arry = np.unique([x_val,y_val,z_val])
pos_arry = pos_arry.tolist()
```

and retrieving the using .at
example

```
std_msgs::Float64MultiArray val = listener.data;
std::cout << val.data.at(0)<< std::endl;
```